# JavaScript Promises sample in JS fiddle not working

Tags: promise, javascript, es6-promise

I have tried the following sample script for a basic JavaScript Promises example on JSFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/QDLup/

```
var promTest = function () {
    return new Promise(function () {      
         alert("This I promise!");
    });
};

promTest().then(function () {
    alert("and then?");
});
```

but it doesn't seem to work. has anyone tried writing a sample script that is (A+ complaint) on JS fiddle ? currently there is chrome 35 and Firefox 30 that supports it as per caniuse http://caniuse.com/promises

Comment: Why not point us to your Fiddle?

Comment: Seems to work just fine http://jsfiddle.net/Dt6bC/

Comment: I don't understand what you were looking for though.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum a sample code using JavaScript promises.

Comment: Ah, in that case check out http://promise-nuggets.github.io/

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum perfect! much appreciated. btw i wonder why did i get 2 down votes ? the fiddles that you shared alongside the answers to contribute to this new topic. imagine someone new to promises and looking for sample code coming across this question and the answer would really add value.

Comment: You didn't link to any attempts you've made on js fiddle or shared any code - I didn't vote but if I had to guess..

Comment: @RichieHindle this is the fiddle i was testing - http://jsfiddle.net/QDLup/

Comment: You don't resolve the promise; why would it do anything?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum you can put your comment in answer, because it did answer my question :)

Comment: @DaveNewton I realized that after I checked the code sample posted in the comments.

Comment: Nope, sorry - I appreciate the thanks but I don't feel that this question poses a specific enough question regarding promises. Feel free to self answer it though.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it more clear. i hope it's better now. Thank you

Comment: I didn't work for me either in IE11.  But it worked in Chrome 55

Answer (score 3):

Managed to fix the error in my fiddle and created a new one: http://jsfiddle.net/FWP9c/1/

and here is a sample code by Benjamin Gruenbaum - http://jsfiddle.net/Dt6bC

```
var delay = function(ms){
    return new Promise(function(resolve){
        setTimeout(resolve,ms); 
    });
};

delay(2000).then(function(){
    alert("Hello World"); 
});
```